# How to ensure a specific index always remains in InnoDB buffer pool?

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have an important table which can be queried by end users of my app. These queries are very important to me, so I want to ensure they will be answered as quickly as possible. In order to do that, I need to make sure relevant indexes used with these queries "always" remain in the innodb_buffer_pool (even if there is a background job running a different query with a different index). Is this possible with MySQL?

Answer (score 1):

Not possible, except by having a buffer_pool that is so big that it never completely fills up.  How much data do you have?  How much RAM?

To "lock" anything into the buffer_pool would *probably* slow down the entire system.  This is because other activity would then be slowed down.

Anyway, a highly active index will tend to stay in the buffer_pool.  That's how an LRU cache works.  (It is not exactly LRU, bot close enough for this discussion.)

If you are having slow queries, let's see them, plus the `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  A common problem is "but I indexed every column", when you should look at the query to decide what indexes to make -- and the best is often "composite" and/or "covering".